# Way of converting formula result to fixed value automatically?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Great forum and helped me many times before! :)

I need specific solution of how to convert(or record) calculated result of formula to fixed value.

Cell K2 contains formula. As soon as value P entered in to cell E2, K2 formula is activated and calculates result. I need this result to be recorded automatically, so even if one or more arguments of formula in K2 are changed value still stay the same as long as cell E2 contains value P, but it resets again if P is removed.

***ADDITIONAL INFORMATION***

As per request I am adding additional material:

[enter image description here][1]

As you can see in the image cell K2 contains formula with multiple expressions and calculations. There are multiple arguments that are used from other sheets and they change from time to time. This formula is activated only if E2=P. So I need solution after formula is activated and value calculated, it needs to stay the same even if one or more expression and argument in original formula has changed.

As possible solution I can see that once E2=P first value can be AUTOMATICALLY copied to another cell and stay unchanged until E2 contains different value and is activated again when E2=P. But how to execute it?
Thanks!

***LINK TO VIDEO EXPLANATION:***

https : // we.tl/t-3aRR3h3d9c

Comment: In your goal, you are required to keep the formula of the cell "K2"? For example, how about replacing the formula with the calculated value as a value? In that case, I thought that it is required to use Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That is exactly what I need. Where should I find this script and how it can be done? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your new questions of `Where should I find this script and how it can be done?`, unfortunately, I cannot find the script for directly using your situation. So in this case, it is required to create the script for your situation. If you want it, can you provide detailed information about your goal? For example, can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image including the explanation?

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Thank you for your time. I updated description and added picture. Hope it is more clear now. Feel free to ask any additional information needed. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Is your added image the sample input situation? If my understanding is correct, where can I see the sample output situation? And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `As possible solution I can see that once E2=P first value can be AUTOMATICALLY copied to another cell and stay unchanged until E2 contains different value and is activated again when E2=P. But how to execute it?`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hey! Input values are in other sheets and I am updating them from time to time. As you can see in image K2 contains formula. That  formula becomes active when I enter P in E2. So I need that calculated result in K2 to become static and do not change after I change other inputs. Hope it is more clear.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Your English seems to be good :) It might be I am having difficult time explain it. I added link to the video that i recorded. Please delete spaces and it should be more clear what do I mean :) Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing the explanation video. From your additional information, I would like to confirm my understanding of your goal. When the value of column "E" is changed to `P`, you want to change the value of column "K" from the formula to the static value by removing the formula. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Best would be if you can make a copy of your spreadsheet and share it. It would be easier to help you this way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.